# Stop Media Playback through adb

Tags: adb, music, intents

I'm testing some settings on a phone, and unfortunately the only control I have is through adb right now. My issue is that while I can start playback of a music file through the following command, I have no way of stopping it so I can perform the next iteration.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.View -d "file:///sdcard/Music/mediatest.mp3" -n "com.android.music/.MediaPlaybackActivity"
```

I don't know if it's possible to end the playback using another adb command, but it doesn't look like it to me - I see [there are no Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.htm) that seem to perform that function, nor [any activities](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r1.2/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackActivity.java?av=f) that are made to stop the media playback.

Comment: When you run the command, does the terminal "lock up" until the song has finished, or does it execute instantly and then return to the terminal prompt?

Answer (score 6):

Use [KeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) to do the job.

```
adb shell input keyevent 85
```

`85` corresponds to `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE`. More keycodes can be found  [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969112/4720957).

Alternatively, if the activity featuring Play/Pause options is in foreground then you can do:

```
adb shell input touchscreen tap <X> <Y>
```

where `<X>` and `<Y>` are the coordinates of the tap that you would perform for Play/Pause using your fingers. See my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/96277) to know how to obtain them (step 1 and 2 under *Instructions for Tasker and Xposed Additions*).

Or, you can opt to completely kill the app using:

```
adb shell am force-stop <PKG_NAME>
```

#### Edit

Kitkat and above has the command `media` whose usage goes as,

```
adb shell media dispatch KEY
```

`KEY` can be play, pause, play-pause, mute, headsethook, stop, next, previous, rewind, record, fast-forword. ([Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r1/cmds/media/src/com/android/commands/media/Media.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F))

Comment: Though launching the app from scratch and sending different Mp3 location as data would also be easy thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped music player using "top" command inside adb shell and killing the process id of music app with superuser(ROOT) access.

Comment: More in depth instructions would make this a nice answer.

Comment: @Peanut top shows the full package name on it, you don't need further explanations. Using keyevents and sending media stop is the way to go.